# Broken rubber seal - leaking toilet cistern

Tags: plumbing, toilet, cistern

[image]

The black rubber dome on the underside of my toilet cistern cracked and flooded my bathroom.

1. What's it called?
2. What's it for?
3. What measurements do I need to make to buy a new one?
4. What tools do I need to replace it? (I tried to turn the hexagon thing by hand, but it won't budge.)
5. How much will it cost to get a plumber to do it, and how long will it take?

When I opened the cistern it was filled with brown residue. I wiped away as much as I could; should I clean it properly with detergent, or just leave it? Also, the black rubber seal is crumbling and is leaving black stains everywhere.

More pictures:

- The leak - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQEbq.jpg
- Brown residue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enczb.jpg
- My bathroom :( - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko4Lm.jpg

Comment: That type of toilet is not used in America as far as i know. On American style toilets that hole would be for the water supply line to connect to a fill valve. You will need to find the manufacturers name and model  and do some research online. your best bet is to contact the manufacturer. It looks like there may be a label on the front of the bowl near the floor.

Comment: It's Australian.

Comment: Ok - but who in Australia makes it ?   What does the label say ?

Comment: Caroma, concrete P 6 Ltr White, P/N 601250W.

Comment: There you go. Now look that up online.  https://www.caroma.com.au/contact-us

Comment: Counting on a piece of rubber in continuity with water to prevent a flood seems like a recipe for disaster.  Rubber always oxidizes with time.  I wonder if that is an access hole for some other thing which might be fitted in there but I cannot imagine what that would be.

Comment: Old thread, but I had a similar issue in UK. Most have an overflow outlet just incase, but this was fitted indoors and therefore not connected with one. The previous seal had gone so I bought and replaced with a 'Flomasta Blanking Plug'. I got 1/2 inch but actually should have got 3/4